# Spring data error

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:my-ctx.xml"})
public class UserTests {
    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private UserRepository getUserRepository() {
        return (UserRepository)applicationContext.getBean("userRepository", CrudRepository.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John Doe");
        getUserRepository().save(user);
    }
}
```

Running the test, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

root cause is

```
 org.datanucleus.api.jpa.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl.isVersion(SingularAttributeImpl.java:79)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.findVersionAttribute(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:92)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:78)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:146)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:84)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:67)
 ...
```

where `VersionMetaData vermd = mmd.getAbstractClassMetaData().getVersionMetaData();` is null.

Is this a bug?

I know that I can put something like `@Inject UserRepository userRepository;`, but taking into account how Spring Data works, these two should have the same result, right? And anyway the result will be the same error.

I'm using Spring data 1.4.1, DataNucleus 3.3.2, Spring 3.2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is a DataNucleus bug and I filled in a bug report (with test and fix patch included): http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCJPA-250.

My workaround was to switch back to Spring Data 1.3.0.